# Did anyone else discover that Jaime pushed Bran from the Broken Tower?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It was only Jaime, Cersei and Bran that knew about what happened in the tower, and Bran could not remember the incident after the fall, leaving only Cersei and Jaime with the knowledge.

However, considering Jaime's new outlook on life after losing his hand (such as him confessing to Brienne why he killed Aerys) and Cersei's wild instability, not to mention the amount of times she was encouraged to "confess", have either of them managed to tell anyone what happened to Bran?

Or has Bran seen what happened to him that day on the tower via Weirwood.net, or possibly has Brynden Rivers seen it?

Or did someone figure it out based on the facts, particularly after it was outed that Cersei and Jaime were sleeping together?

Comment: Considering all the stuff that's happening around them, I doubt they spend much time thinking about Bran.

Comment: I seem to recall Tyrion figuring it out in some book, something about Jaime and Cersei being among the few who stayed in Winterfell when the King went hunting, and that's when Bran fell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some people have in fact figured out that it was The Twins who did the act, more precisely Jaime. Some people just know it.

---

1. **Tyrion:**

Tyrion suspected from the beginning that his siblings may have something to do with Bran's fall. He was keeping an eye out for their reactions when they were breaking fast at Winterfell afterwards.

> Myrcella gave a happy gasp, and Tommen smiled nervously, but it was
>   not the children Tyrion was watching. **The glance that passed between
>   Jaime and Cersei lasted no more than a second, but he did not miss
>   it**. Then his sister dropped her gaze to the table. “That is no
>   mercy. These northern gods are cruel to let the child linger in such
>   pain.”

Later Cersei confirmed it to Tyrion herself in ACOK Chapter 54 when Tyrion tells him that there are reports of murder of Stark boys by Theon Greyjoy:

> "I trust you're pleased," he said as she read. "You wanted the Stark
>   boy dead, I believe."
>
> Cersei made a sour face. "**It was Jaime who threw him from that window**,
>   not me. For love, he said, as if that would please me....when did our
>   sweet brother ever stop to think?"

---

2. **Eddard Stark**

Eddard Stark had suspected Lannister involvement with second assassination attempt (With knife) but Cersei somewhat confirmed the first one as well in AGOT:

> “My son Bran...”
>
> To her credit, Cersei did not look away. “He saw us. You love your
>   children, do you not?” Robert had asked him the very same question,
>   the morning of the melee.

Note how Cersei does not mention throwing the boy out of the window so it may be that Eddard may have been thinking that Cersei confessed about second attempt, not the fall. Or he may have figured out that if Bran saw the twins, his fall was not an accident.

---

3. **Catelyn:**

Catelyn figured out<sup>1</sup> the second attempt after she met Stannis and Renly.

From ACOK:

> Ned must have known, and Lord Arryn before him. Small wonder that the
>   queen had killed them both. Would I do any less for my own? Catelyn
>   clenched her hands, feeling the tightness in her scarred fingers where
>   the assassin’s steel had cut to the bone as she fought to save her
>   son. **“Bran knows too,” she whispered**, lowering her head. Gods be
>   good, **he must have seen something, heard something**, that was why they
>   tried to kill him in his bed.

While She harbored doubts about Bran's accident since the second attempt, she was not sure until she talked with Jaime in ACOK:

> Jaime drank some more wine. “Ask your next.”
>
> Catelyn wondered if he would dare answer her next question with
>   anything but a lie. **“How did my son Bran come to fall?”**
>
> **“I flung him from a window.”**
>
> The easy way he said it took her voice away for an instant. If I had a
>   knife, I would kill him now, she thought, until she remembered the
>   girls. Her throat constricted as she said, “You were a knight, sworn
>   to defend the weak and innocent.”
>
> “He was weak enough, but perhaps not so innocent. He was spying on
>   us."

---

4. **Brienne of Tarth:**

Brienne was standing outside Jaime's cell when Catelyn made Jaime confess about throwing Bran out of the window. Brienne heard everything. From ASOS, Brienne tells Jaime that she heard everything:

> “Talk with Ser Cleos then. I have no words for monsters.”
>
> Jaime hooted. “Are there monsters hereabouts? Hiding beneath the
>   water, perhaps? In that thick of willows? And me without my sword!”
>
> “A man who would violate his own sister, murder his king, and **fling
>   an innocent child to his death** deserves no other name.”

---

5. **Bran:**

Bran himself knows what happened that day and who flung him. The memory came back to him when Clay Cerwyn came to visit Winterfell and his retinue mentioned incest and Lannisters.

From ACOK:

> “He’s a king now too,” Cley confided. “He says Queen Cersei bedded her
>   brother, so Joffrey is a bastard.”
>
> “Joffrey the Illborn,” one of the Cerwyn knights growled. “Small
>   wonder he’s faithless, with the Kingslayer for a father.”
>
> “Aye,” said another, “the gods hate incest. Look how they brought down
>   the Targaryens.”
>
> For a moment Bran felt as though he could not breathe. A giant hand
>   was crushing his chest. He felt as though he was falling, and clutched
>   desperately at Dancer’s reins.
>
> His terror must have shown on his face. “Bran?” Cley Cerwyn said. “Are
>   you unwell? It’s only another king.” . . . . . [Quote skipped]
>
> The pain was an axe splitting his head apart, but when the crow
>   wrenched out its beak all slimy with bits of bone and brain, Bran
>   could see again. What he saw made him gasp in fear. **He was clinging
>   to a tower miles high**, and his fingers were slipping, nails
>   scrabbling at the stone, his legs dragging him down, stupid useless
>   dead legs. **“Help me!”** he cried. **A golden man appeared in the sky
>   above him and pulled him up. “The things I do for love,” he murmured
>   softly as he tossed him out kicking into empty air.**

Later he thinks the following when the Reeds ask him what he is afraid of:

> "The falling, Bran thought, and **the golden man**, **the queen's brother**,
>   he scares me too, but mostly the falling. He did not say it, though.
>   How could he? He had not been able to tell Ser Rodrik or Maester
>   Luwin, and he could not tell the Reeds either. If he didn't talk about
>   it, maybe he would forget. He had never wanted to remember. It might
>   not even be a true remembering."

---

<sub>1. Catelyn was wrong however. Cersei and Jaime were not behind the second attempt</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Catelyn Stark accused Tyrion Lannister after being told by Baelish that the dagger used in an attempt on Bran's life belonged to Tyrion. She didn't know that Jaime and Cersei were actually the ones who hurt Bran, or that they were having an incestuous relationship.

Eddard Stark eventually figured out that Jaime and Cersei were sleeping together and as a result Joffrey isn't actually Robert's son, but is in fact Jaime's, but Eddard never realised that it was in fact Jaime who pushed Bran out of the window.

So as far as I know, Jaime and Cersei are in the clear and nobody knows of the attempted murder besides those who committed it.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to see it via Weirwood.net. But nobody mentioned it - so, we can be sure that nobody saw it.

Another important fact: Catelyn found white hair in the place here Cersei and Jaime did their dirty act.

Catelyn knew that Bran fell from that place. So, she convened a counsel (there was Maester Luwin, Robb, Theon, and some other noble people from Winterfell) and said that she is sure that Bran fell because Lannisters helped him to do that (other evidences were Lysa Arryn's letter and assassin's luxurious dagger)

Comment: She thought it was a Lannister because she received the letter from her sister Lysa, and later thought it was Tyrion when she learns about the knife. She never actually accuses Cersei or Jaime, she just doesn't trust them.

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford but a white hair was also an evidence that it was Lannisters. And the luxurius dagger was also an evidence